# Why there isn't a Null built-in object wrapper?

Tags: javascript, wrapper, built-in

There are four primitive built-in object wrappers (String,Number,Boolean and Symbol(ES6))

Since null is an object why there isn't a Null built-in object wrapper or maybe for undefined too if it is oriented primitive values?

I can't think of a use case but doesn't it make sense?

Comment: Because --> "I can't think of a use case". "Doesn't it make sense?" No.

Comment: @JJJ I can think of a use case.

Comment: Having said that, there's no reason you can't create your own wrapper!

Answer (score 4):

First of all, null is *not* an object. (The reason why `typeof` identifies it as such is the result of a [long-standing bug](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#null).)

The notion of having a null wrapper sounds absurd to me, as that would essentially be the use of an object to represent to the absence of one. Furthermore, it opens up a whole other can of worms when it comes to comparisons and coercion.

What would `new Null() == null` evaluate to? Well, it *is* an object, so it *isn't* null and should return false. Yet, it *represents* null, so it should return true. Or is `new Null() == null` true while `new Null() === null` is false? What about `new Null() == undefined`? Ugh, the JavaScript coercion system is complicated enough as it is.

Furthermore, it's bad enough that JavaScript has two "nothing" values (`null` and `undefined`). Adding a third one (`new Null()`) is a terrible idea.

So, adding `new Null()` would add all this complexity, and for what? What *possible* use can one have for a null object? Being able to set properties and call methods on something that's essentially null? If one would ever need to do something like that, you're either doing it wrong or actually want something closer to Java's `Optional<T>` type.

(And don't get me started on an `undefined` wrapper.)

Comment: "What possible use can one have for a null object?" - to baffle and troll future maintainers of your code by setting properties on a `new Null()` and throwing nulls around that look just like regular objects, obviously `;-)`